# Why is the XQuery expression returning the wrong element count?

Tags: xml, count, xml-parsing, xquery, xquery-3.0

I want return the number of L1 and L0 items per schedule *and* also the number of warnings, also per schedule.

It is actually a "count if" situation.

I tried the following XQuery, which counts L1, L0 and warnings fine, but does count all warnings instead of only the ones with `value = "yes"`.

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $nl := "&#10;"
let $quote := "&#34;"
let $pipe := "&#124;"
let $nodecount := 0

for $profiles in doc("maik test.xml")/PROFILE
for $schedule in $profiles/SCHEDULE
let $schedulename := $schedule/@name
group by $schedulename
return ($nl, 
$schedulename, $pipe, "L0 count:", count($schedule/L0),
$pipe, "L0 Warnings:", count($schedule/L0/ATTRIBUTE[@NAME = "Warnings"]/VALUE/string() = "Yes"),
$pipe, "L1 count:", count($schedule/L0/L1),
$pipe, "L1 Warnings:", count($schedule/L0/L1/ATTRIBUTE[@NAME = "Warnings"]/VALUE/string() = "Yes"))
```

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PROFILE name="profile1">
    <SCHEDULE name="schedule1">
        <L0>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Warnings">
                <VALUE>No</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <L1>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Warnings">
                    <VALUE>No</VALUE>
                </ATTRIBUTE>
            </L1>
            <L1> 
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Warnings">
                    <VALUE>No</VALUE>
                </ATTRIBUTE>
            </L1>
            <L1>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Warnings">
                    <VALUE>Yes</VALUE>
                </ATTRIBUTE>
            </L1>
            <L1></L1>
        </L0>
        <L0>
            <ATTRIBUTE NAME="Warnings">
                <VALUE>No</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <L1></L1>
        </L0>
    </SCHEDULE>
    <SCHEDULE name="schedule2">
        <L0>
            <L1></L1>
            <L1></L1>
            <L1></L1>
            <L1></L1>
        </L0>
        <L0>
            <L1></L1>
        </L0>
        <L0>
            <L1></L1>
            <L1></L1>
            <L1></L1>
        </L0>
    </SCHEDULE>
</PROFILE>
```

Comment: +1 for a good question containing example input, what you've tried and a clear problem statement. For a perfect question, also add the current (wrong) and expected output -- but the question was already totally fine.

Comment: Actually I have a problem with the question. Why are you grouping on schedule name when your schedule names are unique? Are you trying to write a query that can handle input where the schedule names are not unique? If you are, then it's not clear what output you expect in this case.

Comment: @MichaelKay, withouth the grouping my count-function will not work right? I want to know the number of nodes with "warnings value = yes" per schedule.

Comment: @Maik if the groups are all of size one then grouping is completely pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you're also counting the L0-warnings wrong -- but by chance, they're result is the correct one.

Try to return `$schedule/L0/L1/ATTRIBUTE[@NAME = "Warnings"]/VALUE/string() = "Yes"` (without the aggregation) to get a feeling what is going wrong. This subquery returns a boolean which is true if any of the values on the left side matches any of the value on the right side (which in this case, is only a single one). With other words, if *any* of the warnings is `Yes`, the statement gets `true`. If none match at all, `false` is returned. In XQuery, `=` has a set-semantics.

Now, you're counting the number of results, which -- no matter what the boolean result was -- is `1`.

To wrap up, there are two problems in the code:

- Don't use `=` if you want to compare single elements, use `eq` instead (there are also `lq`, `gq`, `le`, `ge` and `ne` for `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `!=`).
- Don't compare the result sequence (which will return a boolean value), but filter it using a predicate.

A proper subquery for the L0 warnings would be

```
count($schedule/L0/ATTRIBUTE[@NME = "Warnings"]/VALUE[string() eq "Yes"])
```

and similarly for the L1 warnings:

```
count($schedule/L0/L1/ATTRIBUTE[@NAME = "Warnings"]/VALUE[string() eq "Yes"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort! It makes perfect sense now. I was not aware of the `VALUE[string() eq "Yes"])` syntax. Really great! Danke und Gruß aus Hamburg!

Answer (score 0):

To be very complete here: this is now the XQuery that works fine:

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $nl := "&#10;"
let $pipe := "&#124;"

for $profiles in doc("maik test.xml")/PROFILE
for $schedule in $profiles/SCHEDULE
let $schedulename := $schedule/@name
group by $schedulename
return ($nl, 
$schedulename, $pipe, "L0 count:", count($schedule/L0),
$pipe, "L0 Warnings:", count($schedule/L0/ATTRIBUTE[@NAME = "Warnings"]/VALUE[string() eq "Yes"]),
$pipe, "L1 count:", count($schedule/L0/L1),
$pipe, "L1 Warnings:", count($schedule/L0/L1/ATTRIBUTE[@NAME = "Warnings"]/VALUE[string() eq "Yes"]))
```